# Is it possible to re-arrange a repository and keep commit history of files that being re-allocated?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

I have a big repo that is connected to a remote repository as well.

I want to re-arrange it but I don't want to apply those changes on the current one so I created a new local directory, a new empty remote repository.

I mirrored my current repo to the new empty remote repository.

Then, I connected the new empty directory to that repostiroy and `git pull` it.

Now I have a full copy of my repository on my local new repository.

I wanted to re-arrange it, and move some files in/outside their current direcotories.

The problem  is that when I do it, and then `commit & push` to the remote repository, I see that all the commit history gets deleted after it moves to the other location.

When I edit files but keep them in their current location, and then `commit & push`, the changes get uploaded and it keeps the commit history.

So the problem is only when I move the files to other directories inside that mirrored repository.

Is there any way to keep the commit history of the commit that were made before the mirror even if I move files?

Thanks.

Comment: A general tip regarding git and renames/moves. You should commit renames and moves of files separately from changes to the file contents. For instance, if you're doing C# which has namespace information inside the files, that typically correspond to the folder structure on disk, if you intend to move the files to different folders/namespaces then you should commit the move separately from fixing the namespace inside. The reason for this is that when files are moved/renamed, git uses heuristics to find the likely source, and if the files changes a lot as well it might not be able to.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm only trying to `move` them, without changing them. And still, it deletes all the commit history that was made before the `mirror`

Comment: When you say "all the commit history gets deleted", can you elaborate on that? What exactly are you looking at? Git doesn't delete commit history (that would largely defeat the purpose), but if you're trying to track the changes to a specific file across a rename you would need to run something like `git log --follow path/to/file` (by default, `git log` does not follow renames).

Comment: @larsks ok so my original repo is on `gitlab`. I mirror it to an empty repo on `github` and then pull that repo (out of github) ot an empty local git repository. Then i'm trying to re-arrange it: move some files around. then I commit and push the changes (of new file locations for these files). Then, when I look in changes made on `github`, and look at the commit history of these files (which were moved out of their original place), I see no commit history. The history that was made before the `mirror` on the original repo.

Comment: @larsks maybe it's only a `github` issue because when I type `git log --follow path/to/file` I do see the full commit history of the files, even if I move them around and change their places. I mean if `ted.c` is located at `/abc` when I mirrored it, and right afterwards I change moved it to `/def` , and I write `--folow /def/ted.c` I can still see the whole history that was made before. But if I look at `def/ted.c` on `github`, I don't see the commit history of that file.

Comment: I don't think github has a mechanism for following file renames.

Comment: @larsks indeed my friend, thanks for your answer. For anyone who will reach this question, this is how I did it - I just mirrored my original repo to an other one on `gitlab` which DOES support the mechanism of file renames , and after dealing with the repo while it's connected to `gitlab`, I just mirrored it to `github`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. You create a branch which will remain unchanged, `checkout` your main branch and perform the changes. You do not need to merge these branches, you will have the old commit history in the branch which was created for this purpose and the new commit history in your main branch, `master`.

EDIT

Let's assume that you are on the `master` branch.

Perform:

```
git branch archive
git checkout archive
git push -u origin archive
```

This creates a branch in your repository and then updates it on the remote repository.

Now, perform

```
git checkout master
mv myfolder1/myfile myfolder2
git add .
git commit
git push
```

View

```
git log
```

You will see that the old history is lost. But now perform

```
git checkout archive
git log
```

And you will see that in the archive branch you have all the commit history of the file prior of its moving.

Comment: I can't understand your answer.
I'll explain my self - Is it possible to move files between different directories and still keep their commit history? Because when I `git mv` a file into another directory inside the repo, and push changes, both `github` and `gitlab` show that there is no commit history for that moved file.

Comment: @NoobCoder I have edited my answer, adding more details. Hopefully it's now clearer.